# Making a better caramel for granola bar

Tags: sugar, granola

I came up with a recipe of granola bars where I melt

- 10 tbsp of brown sugar
- 4 tbsp of honey
- 4 tbsp of soy oil
- 2 tbsp of water
- Vanilla extract

and mix with 4 cups of rolled oats + 1 cup of rice crispies, put it in a pan and bake it for 20 min at 200ºC/330ºF. After cooling, I get a nice and firm granola bar for about one day, after that the bar gets soft and starts crumbling.

How can I adjust my recipe to make my bar more solid and for longer?

Comment: Brown sugar is hygroscopic (it attracts water) so that is going to have a tendency to soften things up.

Answer (score 2):

If it stays the right texture for the first day, I would say the problem is more with the way you store it than the recipe. Granola bars need to be stored in an airtight container, somewhere dry and cool to maintain their texture for as long as possible.

Comment: +1 The foil/mylar packaging on the commercial ones is not just for looks....